# Plot binomial GAM in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to visualize a dataset that uses a binomial response variable (proportions).  I'm using a gam to examine the trend, but having difficult getting it to plot with ggplot. How do I get the smooth added to the plot?

Example:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(y1 = sample.int(100),
                 y2 = sample.int(100),
                 x  = runif(100, 0, 100))
ggplot(data = df,
      aes(y = y1/(y1+y2), x = x)) +
  geom_point(shape = 1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "gam",
              method.args = list(family = binomial),
              formula = cbind(y1, y2) ~ s(x))

Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`
Caused by error in `cbind()`:
! object 'y1' not found
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula in `geom_smooth` has to be in terms of `x` and `y`, representing the variables on your x and y axes, so you can't pass in `y1` and `y2`.

The way round this is that rather than attempting to use the `cbind` type left-hand side of your `gam`, you can expand the counts into 1s and 0s so that there is only a single y variable. Although this makes for a little extra pre-processing, it allows you to draw your points just as easily using `stat = 'summary'` inside `geom_point` and makes your `geom_smooth` very straightforward:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(y1 = sample.int(100),
                 y2 = sample.int(100),
                 x  = runif(100, 0, 100))

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  summarize(y = rep(c(1, 0), times = c(y1, y2)), x = x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(stat = 'summary', fun = mean, shape = 1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "gam",
              method.args = list(family = binomial),
              formula = y ~ s(x)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks!  I would not have thought about that approach.